# How do you set gcAllowVeryLargeObjects in coreCLR?

Tags: asp.net-core, coreclr

Now that there isn't a `app.config`, how do you set gcAllowVeryLargeObjects to true so that you can allocate big arrays?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the corresponding [environment variable](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/clr-configuration-knobs.md#environmentregistry-configuration-knobs); just remember to use the `COMPlus_` prefix (e.g. `COMPlus_gcAllowVeryLargeObjects=1`).

You can either set this up from the command line before running dotnet run, or add it on the environment variables section of the project's properties within Visual Studio (or probably add a registry entry).

Comment: Link is dead. Are there new instructions some where?

Comment: Ok this is no longer applicable and set by default.

Comment: Seems like this does not help `HashSet<Int64>` to have over 100k entries :(

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 | Page not found"*. See https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/27612 and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#allow-large-objects